# Многоядерная обработка Java-программы

Tags: java, многопоточность

Помогите разобраться с многоядерной обработкой Java-программы.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании класса `Thread` и интерфейса `Runnable` Java-программа будет использовать многопоточность только на одном ядре центрального процессора, при наличии других ядер?

А для реализации многоядерной обработки Java-программы необходимо использовать специализированные Java-классы, например, Fork/Join Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не правильно. Java уже давно использует нативные нити. А раскидкой по ядрам занимается уже сама операционная система.

Так что, даже при использовании `Thread` и `Runnable` ваши нити могут быть разбросаны операционной системой по разным ядрам.

Тут вообще вопрос больше концептуальный. `fork` - создаёт дочерний **процесс**, а у него внутри уже свои нити. Следовательно, `fork` потяжелее будет. Форкать лучше, если вы хотите запустить, по сути, копию задачи.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, а какой из способов многоядерной обработки является эффективней: нативные нити или тот же Fork/Join Framework? Или сейчас Fork/Join используется для других целей?

Comment: @Алексей форк для немного других задач, когда вам копию текущего процесса надо, например. В большинстве случаев я бы рекомендовал просто нити создавать.

Comment: _fork - это копия процесса_ - может лучше переформулировать - fork создаёт дочерний процесс и тогда речь идёт о многопроцессности.

Comment: @0xdb спасибо. Хорошее дополнение)